# Delphi: Android Exception closes my app

Tags: android, delphi

I am have a problem in the applications, I am using Delphi XE7 and running applications on Android 6.0 or higher, but when it presents an error it closes the application instead of handling and displaying the error message. I'm already aware that I should upgrade my delphi so that my applications work on versions of android 6.0 or higher. But I wanted to be able to handle Delphi XE7 by trying to "work around" this problem so I would not have to go through the inconvenience of installing Delphi Berlin for example to work.

Anyone have a idea a solution the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you need to track the exception in the `Application.OnException := MyExceptionHandler`. this is only for the main thread, after you need to do the same on background thread. Excellent article here: https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/02/21/build-your-own-error-reporter-part-2-android/

Answer (score 0):

If you put your code between `Try..Except` blocks you will be able to fence app broke, and read the message contents, using structure above:

```
Try
    Your code here
Except
on E:Exception do
    Showmessage('Error in module {your modulename}'+E.Message);
end;
```

The problem is you need to do it In many parts or modules of your app. However, don't forget that this is best practice.

Another alternative, you can Compile your app for Windows first, and debug using break points.

If, for instance, you have some code just works on Android, put the code between directives

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
{$ENDIF}
```

For example, a fragment of my SQLConection to show this idea

```
try
DataModule.Connection1.Params.Values['DriverID'] := 'SQLite';
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    DataModule2.Connection1.Params.Values['Database'] := 'C:/Data/test_DATABASE.sql';
  {$ENDIF}

  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
    DataModule2.Connection1.Params.Values['Database'] := GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'DATABASE.sql';
  {$ENDIF}
Except
    on E:Exception do
        Showmessage('Error on dataload ...'+E.Message);
    end;
```

Comment: my problem is my app close when try...except in Android 6.0 or higher, u have same problem?... i am use Delphi XE7.

Comment: Yes, shure, That occours many times on my App. Always I traced it with E.message and found the Error origns. Please, put your Code here for everybody look the error together. If you have Error description (as E.message o IException type) please share with us as well.

Comment: what delphi you use?

Comment: DXE7. I am also brasilian. Invite in chat if you wait

Comment: Yes, sure. I hope keep conversation in English to help another people of community. Do you know how to invok the chat?

Comment: i dont know, how?

Comment: I dont know also rsrsrss. Please, paste your function. Posta o código aee

Comment: i see have summer 2015 hotfix for XE7, u have?

Comment: I dont know. Actually, if you post the code is best, perhaps that is not the error reason. Are your code very large?

Comment: yes, look your version Delphi XE7, in Help->About Embarcedero ... my version Embarcadero® Delphi XE7 Version 21.0.17707.5020 and u?

Comment: 21.0.17707.3725 But I am quite shure that this is not your problem. I hope help you, but without the code it is impossible. Did you try compile for windows and debug with breakpoint? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"